# Why did I get unexpected field names: ['is_dynamic_op']?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a low light video processing project where I am getting some errors in some areas,
For this code.

```
params = trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS._replace(
    precision_mode='FP16',
    is_dynamic_op = True)
```

I am getting this error.

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-8-326230ed5373> in <module>()
>       2 params = trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS._replace(
>       3     precision_mode='FP16',
> ----> 4     is_dynamic_op = True)
>       5 
>       6 # Convert the model
> 
> /usr/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py in _replace(_self, **kwds)
>     414         result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, field_names, _self))
>     415         if kwds:
> --> 416             raise ValueError(f'Got unexpected field names: {list(kwds)!r}')
>     417         return result
>     418 
> 
> ValueError: Got unexpected field names: ['is_dynamic_op']
```

I have used these libraries,

```
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mirnet.inference import Inferer
from mirnet.utils import download_dataset, plot_result
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
```

I have imported all the libraries but am still stuck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems that `trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS` doesn't have the field `'is_dynamic_op'`. My guess would be that, some documentation exists for the library, and there you can probably see whether the field is settable or not.

Secondly, it seems you are using TensorFlow and the TensorRT API. (but again, it's a guess...). In the source-code of the library, they use "is_dynamic_op" on some "rewrite_config". Maybe this helps you reformat your code to work: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dd38449b8ac3fd9ffaa98349d39d36ec26e72dfe/tensorflow/python/compiler/tensorrt/trt_convert.py#L1136

Comment: Please take a look at this code, [link]https://colab.research.google.com/github/sayakpaul/MIRNet-TFLite/blob/main/MIRNet_TRT.ipynb

It is showing the error when I try to run Codeblock [8].